# Navigation Controller show/push viewcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, view, barcode

I have a problem in my code the `self.navigationController.pushViewController` function is being called infinite time, my code is attached, I am getting a product information by reading its barcode.

More details:More details:
More details:
More details:More details:

```
func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let nav = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("companyInfoNAv") as! UINavigationController
    let companyInfoView = nav.topViewController as! CompanyInformationViewController  //      toggleFlash()
    for meta_Data in metadataObjects {

        let decoded_data: AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject = meta_Data as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

        self.output_Label.text = decoded_data.stringValue
        self.reader_Type.text = decoded_data.type



        let manager: AFHTTPSessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager.init()
        manager.GET("https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/"+decoded_data.stringValue+"?apikey="+"944b2810f5072d9d125f5fcf32543r1", parameters: nil, success: { (NSURLSessionDataTask, responseObject) in

            self.arrayObjects = responseObject as! NSDictionary

            print(self.arrayObjects)


            if(( self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("name")?.empty) == nil){
                let attributes : NSDictionary!

                attributes = self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("attributes") as! NSDictionary
                if(attributes.count > 3){
                    if(attributes.objectForKey("Manufacturer")?.empty == nil){
                        companyInfoView.companyName = attributes.objectForKey("Manufacturer") as! NSString as String


                    }
                }else{

                    companyInfoView.companyName = "No Name in DATABASE"


                }
            }
            else{
                companyInfoView.companyName = "No Name in DATABASE"

            }


            print(self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("name"))
            }, failure: { (operation, error) in
                print(error)
        })





    }
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(companyInfoView, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: You have linked your scannerPage with companyInfoView in your storyboard?

Answer (score 0):

your API manager is executing asynchronously, you should push the `navigation controller` inside the `success` block as below, or using completion

```
manager.GET("https://api.outpan.com/v2/products/"+decoded_data.stringValue+"?apikey="+"944b2810f5072d9d125f5fc1217855f1", parameters: nil, success: { (NSURLSessionDataTask, responseObject) in

        self.arrayObjects = responseObject as! NSDictionary

        print(self.arrayObjects)


        if(( self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("name")?.empty) == nil){
            let attributes : NSDictionary!

            attributes = self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("attributes") as! NSDictionary
            if(attributes.count > 3){
                if(attributes.objectForKey("Manufacturer")?.empty == nil){
                    companyInfoView.companyName = attributes.objectForKey("Manufacturer") as! NSString as String


                }
            }else{

                companyInfoView.companyName = "No Name in DATABASE"


            }
        }
        else{
            companyInfoView.companyName = "No Name in DATABASE"

        }


        print(self.arrayObjects.objectForKey("name"))
        // push the navigation controller here
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(companyInfoView, animated: true)

        }, failure: { (operation, error) in
            print(error)
    })
```